# Posting invoice item with Tracking Category and Tracking Option?

Tags: json

Is this the correct json POST request to the Xero API endpoint for creating an invoice item with 2 Tracking Category's and Tracking Option's?

`{ "Description": "Product XYZ", "Quantity": 5, "UnitAmount": 100, "AccountCode": "200", "Tracking": [ { "TrackingCategoryID": "your_tracking_category_id", "TrackingOptionID": "your_tracking_option_id" }, { "TrackingCategoryID": "your_tracking_category_id", "TrackingOptionID": "your_tracking_option_id" } ] }`

No, I did not try. I could not find any documentation.